# How to create different color for Longleave, Fullday, HalfDay in scheduler dhtmlx?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am new to Scheduler https://docs.dhtmlx.com/

How to change the color as per Holiday type. For example:- Fullday(Single day and long leave), Single Halfday (Am and Pm) and sick leave.

```
$.each(JSON.parse(result.engineerHolidayList), function (key, value) {
    scheduler.addMarkedTimespan({
        start_date: new Date(value.StartYear, value.StartMonth, value.StartDate, value.StartTime),
        end_date: new Date(value.EndYear, value.EndMonth, value.EndDate, value.EndTime),
        css: "worktime",
        type: "dhx_time_block",
        sections: {
            "timeline": [value.section_id]
        }
    });
});
```

I want to change the color as per leave red, blue, green etc.
During holiday time, that calender is on-editable.

Comment: which calendar you are using?

Comment: @NegiRox Scheduler Calender - Day view and Week view 
  https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/day_view.html

Comment: Currently I am using if condition   if (value.StartTime == 0 && value.EndTime == 24) {} but sick leave is different, that is in all  category like full, half, long

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, you just need to update the value of `css` property in `addMarkedTimespan` method (see the [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/qv6k0y)) and add color in CSS for the specified class.

```
css:"gray" //draws a DIV and applies the 'gray' css class to it
```

Please check [this sample](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/samples/09_api/04_highlighted_sections_units.html) with several marked timespans that have different colors\styles.

Also, you can find more details about this and other properties of `addMarkedTimespan` method in the documentation [here](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_addmarkedtimespan.html).

Comment: HI, Css: gray is ok, but during half day, full day, sickday - So I need different css will load as per leave type.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need **attacchEvent** function where you need to bind **onTemplatesReady** to give different colors to your events.

```
scheduler.attachEvent("onTemplatesReady", function(){

  function findInArray(array, key) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (key == array[i].key)
        return array[i];
    }
    return null;
  }

  function getRoomType(key) {
    return findInArray(scheduler.serverList("roomTypes"), key).label;
  }

  function getRoomStatus(key) {
    return findInArray(scheduler.serverList("roomStatuses"), key);
  }

  function getRoom(key) {
    return findInArray(scheduler.serverList("rooms"), key);
  }

  scheduler.templates.timeline_scale_label = function (key, label, section) {
    var roomStatus = getRoomStatus(section.status);
    return ["<div class='timeline_item_separator'></div>",
            "<div class='timeline_item_cell'>" + label + "</div>",
            "<div class='timeline_item_separator'></div>",
            "<div class='timeline_item_cell'>" + getRoomType(section.type) + "</div>",
            "<div class='timeline_item_separator'></div>",
            "<div class='timeline_item_cell room_status'>",
            "<span class='room_status_indicator room_status_indicator_"+section.status+"'></span>",
            "<span class='status-label'>" + roomStatus.label + "</span>",
            "</div>"].join("");
  };

  scheduler.templates.event_class = function (start, end, event) {
      return "event_" + (event.status || "");
  };
});
```

here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/mx2d95wj/).